# Can you be the judge of your injury ( i.e. broken neck) and decide on the best time to return on the bike?

Tags: road-bike

I have broken neck and wasn't planning to take a break at this point in the season. Doctor would always point to full rest, but can it be better to get back on the bike without further ado? Be careful

Comment: "would always" - does this mean you haven't actually asked? Many doctors will say "listen to your body". They may also advise being extra cautious, an unhealed injury to the neck could mean that if you ride you'll be and feel fine, but if you crash, instead of a ruined season if you waited, you go into a casket. Or it might not matter and they'll say exercising will improve your outcomes. Only your doctor will know.

Comment: Are you asking a legitimate question or are you looking for validation of what you intend to do anyway ?

Comment: If you're desperate to get on a bike, maybe check with your doctor about stationary bike or trainer.  not really too sure about the nature of your injuries but at least that takes some risk out of the picture

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is seeking medical advice.

Comment: Only you can judge what is right for you. In most countries doctors are obligated to give you the information for you to make an informed decision.  Some countries have laws against jumping out of planes without a parachute, probably because they do not have laws that make it illegal to ignore your doctor's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your doctor knows your health condition better than random people on the Internet. I would trust a medical professional, especially for a serious injury such as a broken neck. You may think you are going well enough to ride your bike, but it may be just you trying to convince yourself very hard because you want it. Your doctor has a detached view of the situation, and takes decisions based on facts (scan/MRI results, medical reports, examinations, other similar cases, etc) and has a deep knowledge of the human body.

Comment: I had light fracture of neck. My question was would a cyclist be kept off the bike, or would everything be done to keep him on ? Personally I think in some cases all the rider closest bubble will go the extra mile to do everything in their capacities to keep him riding - see how many bash their pelvis and are pushed by the ds to continue ( Dan martin in my latest experience to name one ) . In my personal case against the best advice of resting, I kept riding through the injury with a collar ( although I felt I could do it my body told me) and was fine with the recovery and doctors support.